# IIS 10 giving 401.3 access denied for PUT, DELETE, or PATCH for specific path

Tags: rest, iis, handlers, http-verbs

I'm working on a REST API, and doing test and prototype work on Windows 10 with its native IIS install. The API is written in C#. I've created a class that derives from IHttpHandler, and derive from that to implement classes for my API's nouns. (This allows me to commonalize logging, config, auditing, etc, in my base noun class). To implement verbs, the derived classes override the base class' functions for GET, POST, etc.

Anyway, one of the nouns I have is for access to the application's log. The path for this is /log. In it I've implemented GET, to read the log, and DELETE, to clear the log. GET works fine, however, DELETE gives me a 401.3 from IIS. I also get the same 401.3 if I try PUT or PATCH. PUT and PATCH are not implemented in the Logging class, so they should return a not implemented message. I do get the not implemented message if I try POST (which is not implemented in exactly the same way that PUT and PATCH are not implemented).

As part of trying to narrow down this behavior, I checked whether there were specific verbs being blocked by request filtering (there weren't). I checked whether Process Monitor was catching file system access denials at the underlying path (it wasn't... things never got that far.) I then tried adding another handler mapping - exactly the same as the first, but with a different path name:

<handlers>

```
<add name="BLOBRepoLog" path="log" verb="*" type="BLOBRepoService.Log" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" >

<add name="BLOBRepoLogSanityCheck" path="foo" verb="*" type="BLOBRepoService.Log" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" >
```

</handlers>

Using Postman, if I call DELETE on /log, I get the 401.3. If I call DELETE on /foo, it works correctly. If I call PUT on /log I get the 401.3. If I call PUT on /foo, I get the correct not implemented message.

Anyone have an idea why IIS should be doing extra scrutiny on verbs called for the /log path?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where Put and Delete weren't working, it turned out for me that Webdav was the issue. In my case I didn't really need it so I uninstalled it and everything worked.